# Produce multiple plots from comparison of two rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Example database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmOu6.png)

For each item I want to plot the 5 different prices for both days on the same axis.

I can plot for just one item (i.e "a") but I want to produce multiple graphs and save them automatically.

My actual data set is much larger than the example.

I have been working with this code to try save the graphs, but it is doesn't quite work:

```
 mypath <- file.path("C:","R","SAVEHERE",paste("myplot_", names[i], ".jpg", 
sep = ""))

 jpg(file=mypath)
    mytitle = paste("my title is", names[i])
    plot(x,y, main = mytitle)
 dev.off()
```

EDIT:
This the code I am using to produce 1 graph.

```
filter(name== "a")

w2=data.table(w2)
w3 = melt.data.table(data=w2, id.vars=c("Day", "Name"))

wplot = ggplot(w3, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
geom_point(aes(color=Day)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + ylim(-100, 300)

plot(wplot)
```

The graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVaZN.png).
I want it to loop through all the names and save graphs that look like the second photo. I hope this information is more helpful than my initial post!

thank you

Comment: Please dont post images of code. post the actual data (or a small subset) by editing your question to include the output from dput(head(data))

Comment: Please post the plot of one item and describe what *doesn't quite work right* mean.

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly hard to help because you provide so little code but perhaps plot.new():

```
plot.new()
jpg(file=mypath)
mytitle = paste("my title is", names[i])
plot(x,y, main = mytitle)
dev.off()
```

If you make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and also tell us what specifically isn't working we will be able to better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this

```
    Names=levels(q$Name)

for(i in 1:length(Names)){

  mypath <- file.path("C:", "Users", "myname", "Documents", "Plots",paste("myplot_",
                                                                           Names[i], ".jpg", sep = ""))

  jpeg(file=mypath)

  q4 = filter(q3, q3$Name == Names[i])

  qplot = ggplot(q4, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_point(aes(color=TableName)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + ylim(-100, 300) + 
    labs(title = Names[i], color = "Legend") +xlab("") + ylab("Price")

  plot(qplot)
  dev.off()
}
```

Based off this
https://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/